# How do I upload an attachment to a JIRA issue via powershell?

Tags: powershell, curl, jira, attachment

I have been searching online for a while and I've not found a solid answer to this (lots of partial answers, though).  Still nothing I do works.

I'm trying to write a powershell script to send attachments to JIRA using cURL (have not found another way that I can get to work).
My cURL command is:

```
C:\opt\curl\curl.exe -u user:pa$$word -X POST -H "X-Atlassian-Token: nocheck" -F "file=@C:\opt\attachments\75391_testingPNG.png" http://jira.ourURL.com/rest/api/2/issue/75391/attachments
```

This works perfectly from the command line.  Anytime I try to run it via powershell it bombs out.  Seems like it should be very easy to do, though.  Just want to grab the files from a directory and send them to JIRA.

Anyone have any thoughts about this???  Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect that the characters $ and @ in the arguments could be causing you problems (In case that is what you are using). Try escaping them using the backtick symbol.

To start curl.exe using the specified parameters, try the following command:

```
Start-Process C:\opt\curl\curl.exe -argumentList "-u", "user:pa`$`$Word", "-X", "POST", "-H", "`"X-Atlassian-Token: nocheck`"", "-F", "`"file=`@C:\opt\attachments\75391_testingPNG.png`"",  "http://jira.ourURL.com/rest/api/2/issue/75391/attachments"
```

Basically it means that where you would separate arguments with a space in a command prompt, you would send each argument as an element in a powershell string Array and use it as the value in the -argumentlist parameter to Start-Process.

Comment: Well, that seems to do a little.  Though it fails trying to resolve the host nocheck.  So, it appears that it is not running the command properly, still.  And if I remove that it does nothing (not sure if JIRA is blocking it because the nocheck is missing?).

Comment: Did you try to use "X-Atlassian-Token:nocheck" instead? (No space after colon)

Comment: That does stop that error...  Though, it does not authenticate properly now.  Just returns a 403, like it is not sending the username and password correctly.

Comment: I Think i got it. Try the command above again. I changed it so the double quotations in the original command is kept.

Comment: That did it.  Now I see... :)  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

If you're using PowerShell 3+, you can use the native method `Invoke-RestMethod` to talk to JIRA, and not have to worry about escaping characters to shell out to a command:

```psh
# Build a basic auth header:

$headers = @{ 
    'Authorization' = "Basic $([System.Convert]::ToBase64String([System.Text.Encoding]::ASCII.GetBytes(("{0}:{1}" -f $UserName, $Password))))" 
    'X-Atlassian-Token' = 'nocheck'
}
Invoke-RestMethod -Uri "http://jira.ourURL.com/rest/api/2/issue/75391/attachments" -Method Post -InFile "C:\opt\attachments\75391_testingPNG.png" -ContentType "multipart/form-data" -Headers $headers
```

I'm actually not sure what the `nocheck` header you're adding does though; I've not needed it when talking to JIRA over REST.